# How do I fix this syntax error? I am confused

Tags: python, syntax-error

Here is all my coding that I did but I keep getting this syntax error. It will be explained more at the bottom.

```
def main():
    ActualValue()
    AssessedValue()
    printResult()

def ActualValue()
    global actual_value
    actual_value = float(input("Enter actual value:\t"))

def AssessedValue()
    global assessed_value
    global property_tax
    assessed_value = 0.6 * actual_value
    property_tax = assessed_value / 100 * 0.64

def printResult():
    print "n\For a property valued at $", actual_value
    print "The assessed value is $", assessed_value
    print "The property tax is $", property_tax

actual_value = None
assessed_value = None
property_tax = None

main()
```

That is my code:

It keeps saying that I have a syntax error:

```
def printResult():
    print "n\For a property valued at $", actual_value
    print "The assessed value is $", assessed_value
    print "The property tax is $", property_tax
```

Comment: Please include the entire actual error message in your post.  Also are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Is this Python 2.7 or 3?

Comment: "print" is a function in python3

Comment: print "The assessed value is $", assessed_value    -  the quotations on the right has the syntax... $"

Answer (score 5):

You have the `\n` escape sequence backwards.

Also, you need to make sure all your function definitions have a colon on the end of the line.

Also, `print` is a function in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

`print` is a function in Python 3:

```
def printResult():
    print("\nFor a property valued at $", actual_value)
    print("The assessed value is $", assessed_value)
    print("The property tax is $", property_tax)
```

I fixed your `\n` newline escape code for you as well.

You probably want to use the [`.format()` method](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/string.html#formatstrings) to format your output:

```
def printResult():
    print("\nFor a property valued at ${0}".format(actual_value))
    print("The assessed value is ${0}".format(assessed_value))
    print("The property tax is ${0}".format(property_tax))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify what Platinum Azure said.

```
def main():
    actualValue()
    assessedValue()
    printResult()

def actualValue():
    global actual_value
    actual_value = float(input("Enter actual value:\t"))

def assessedValue():
    global assessed_value
    global property_tax
    assessed_value = 0.6 * actual_value
    property_tax = assessed_value / 100 * 0.64

def printResult():
    print "\nFor a property valued at $", actual_value
    print "The assessed value is $", assessed_value
    print "The property tax is $", property_tax

actual_value = None
assessed_value = None
property_tax = None

main()
```

This should work

Comment: Its also good to use the standard language variable name case. In python ActualValue is a class name a method should be actualValue or better actual_value